# Choosing the correct server rack width

Tags: rack, rackmount

I am required to setup a server rack 42HE that keeps some 2HE rack servers with following dimensions:

89 mm (H), 437 mm (W), 647 mm (D)

The rack i want is a 19" one and available in these dimensions:

2000 mm (H), 800 mm (W), 1000 mm (D) <--- This one i want

2000 mm (H), 600 mm (W), 1000 mm (D)

**My question is: Will the 800mm (W) be to wide?? Or is it just so you have more space for cabeling etc.?**

For reference: The rack i would like to get is [Rittal Model DK 5509.161](http://www.rittal.com/uk-en/product/show/variantdetail.action?productID=5509161).

Sorry if this question is silly but i rather take the shame than choosing the wrong rack :)

Comment: How could we possibly know what would be "too wide" for you? It depends on where you're trying to fit it. They're both 19" racks so the inside dimensions of the racking posts will fit your equipment, if that's what you're confused about.

Comment: Yes that is my confusion.. I was not sure if the 437 mm wide server would fit into the racking posts of a 800 mm wide rack. But i understand that those rack posts are made to fit 437 mm wide servers, and the "extra space" is advantageous for cabling.

Comment: The rack, in either case, is 19 inches. The overall enclosures have different widths.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I am confident now with the 800mm choice based on my research and your comments ultimately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both 19" racks so the inside dimensions of the racking posts will fit your equipment, if that's what you're confused about. The overall enclosures have different widths.

Answer (score 2):

We tend to use the 800mm wide ones for network and fibre-channel switches to accommodate the extra cabling requirements and then use 600mm ones for servers/storage etc. where the cabling tends to be lighter - you can mix and match them don't forget.